# python get line+1 from text file

Tags: python, string, file, text

I have a file I am looking for a particular sting called "$INGGA". My code prints all the lines with this string but I also want the string from the next line. How do I go about doing this? My current code is:

```
with open(nmea) as nmeafile:
    for num, line in enumerate(nmeafile, 1):
        if "$INGGA" in line:
            print line
            # add code to print the line+1
```

Many Thanks

Phil

Comment: Just call next on the file object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `itertools` recipe `pairwise`, it will yield the current and the next line per iteration. You check the first one and yield both.

For a file

```
asd
hello
$INGGA
argh
fpp
$INGGA
cake
sausage
```

it will return

```
$INGGA
argh
$INGGA
cake
```

All processing is done out of RAM (the file is read and processed line by line) and there are no procedural variables (setting a flag in one iteration, resetting in the next).

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)


def ingga(nmeafile):
    for line, nextline in pairwise(nmeafile):
        if "$INGGA" in line:
            yield line
            yield nextline

with open("nmea") as nmeafile:
    for i in ingga(nmeafile):
        print i,
```

Or, if you don't need a reusable function

```
with open("nmea") as nmeafile:
    for line, nextline in pairwise(nmeafile):
        if "$INGGA" in line:
            print line,
            print nextline,
```

Comment: what if $INGGA is the last line?

Comment: It will not be printed, `line` never reaches the end of file (`nextline` never contains first row)

Comment: HI, excellent answer, How would I go about joining the line + nextline into a new string so I can output into a next textfile?

Comment: what do you mean by joining them? put them on one line?

Answer (score 1):

The easier solution here is to place a conditional so that you print the next line when it's its turn in the iterator. Because if you try to print it in the turn before it may not be there (i.e. If $INGGA is the last line)

```
should_print, text = False, ''
with open(nmea) as nmeafile:
    for num, line in enumerate(nmeafile, 1):
        if should_print:
            print '{0}, {1}'.format(text, line)
            should_print = False
        if "$INGGA" in line:
            should_print, text = True, line
```

Comment: "best" is quite subjective in this case. i for one almost always prefer using `itertools` instead of procedural loops (using a variable across several loop iterations).

Comment: True, probably should have said easier. And I'm gonna edit ;)

Comment: how would I go about combining the two lines into a new string i.e: I have "%INGGA 25, 27, 28, 29 on one line then the next line "%INHDT 54, 37, 48 and I want to make a new string of  "%INGGA 25, 27, 28, 29, %INHDT 54, 37, 48"

Answer (score 0):

Here's my preferred method. Read the lines into a list, and then iterate through until the next to last element, preventing you from attempting to print a nonexistent line.

```
with open("info.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in xrange(len(lines)-1):
        if "$INGGA" in line:
            print lines[i]
            print lines[i+1]
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this, you will read the entire file into RAM.